# Create table structure from XML - PostgreSQL 10

Tags: xml, database, postgresql

Is there a way for me to create a table from an XML file.... not sure about the exact XML structure but probably like this:

```
     <TableStructure tablename="Table_From_XML">
    <Col type="serial">Column1</Col>
    <Col type="integer">Column2</Col>
    <Col type="varchar">Column3</Col>
</TableStructure>
```

Any help/comments are appreciated...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way, probably many ways, the one I chose was a Python one. Very briefly

```
import lxml.etree as ET
ET.parse(xsl_filename)
```

The xsl_filename is an xslt which allows use such as "for-each" (xpath) and "select" and "if test". The output file contains a bunch of sql create table and inserts which get loaded to Postgresql via psycopg2. Works well for me. You will have a bit of work to do.